# Log-Binomial Polynomial Terms Interpretation

Tags: logistic, polynomial

I have a log binomial model of tested (yes/no) by number of years since 2011. The quadratic term is also significant. I am trying to find the probability of being tested at each year. I thought I would use estimate statements to do so; however, I am getting probabilities that are greater than 1, which is obviously incorrect. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
proc genmod data = DATA ;
    model Tested (event='1')=  YearDiag2011|YearDiag2011
            / dist=bin link=log type3 aggregate ;
estimate '11' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 0 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 0;
estimate '12' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 1 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 1;
estimate '13' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 2 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 2 ;
estimate '14' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 3 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 3 ;
estimate '15' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 4 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 4;
estimate '16' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 5 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 5 ;
estimate '17' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 6 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 6 ;
estimate '18' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 7 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 7 ;
estimate '19' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 8 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 8 ;
estimate '20' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 9 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 9 ;
estimate '21' intercept 1 YearDiag2011 10 YearDiag2011*YearDiag2011 10;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: *How* are you finding these "probabilities"?  Are you perhaps writing a command to return their log odds?

Comment: I used estimate statements imputing values of 0-10. It's log-binomial, not logistic, so I don't believe they are odds or log odds.